# Functor with right-adjoint right-inverse is a fibration?

Tags: reference-request, simplicial-stuff

In a few papers by Bourn, he seemingly writes that a functor with a right-adjoint right-inverse is a fibration. For instance, the truncation functor from $(n+1)$-truncated semisimplicial objects to $n$-truncated semisimplicial objects admits the coskeleton functor as a right-adjoint right-inverse, and immediately following this observation Bourn writes that the truncation functor is a fibration.

Is a functor with a right-adjoint right-inverse a fibration? What are the Cartesian arrows? Where can I read about this?

Comment: The connection I've seen for fibrations in general is as briefly described in [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Street+fibration#in_terms_of_adjoint_inverses).

Comment: @DerekElkins it's hard for me to unpack all of that information, and I also don't understand why the existence of a right-adjoint right-inverse implies the left adjoint is a fibration (without mentioning slices).

Comment: It is next to impossible to say *anything* about fibrations without mentioning slices. Why do you want to avoid them??

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Sorry, my comment was unclear. I tried to say that Bourn's remark does not mention slices - the existence of a right-adjoint right-inverse to the functor itself (not to the slice functor of the nlab) seems to imply its a fibration.

Comment: Oh I see now. One more thing: at the end of the nLab entry that @DerekElkins links to, you may find `Any left exact (or, more generally, “semi-left exact”) reflection is a Street fibration, not generally Grothendieck`. Maybe this means that Bourn uses some additional condition; I don't know what semi-left exact means but it seems to be the key...